# Wrong dictionary in spotlight for macOS

Tags: macos, spotlight, language, dictionary

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro with macOS 10.12 Sierra. I can hit `cmd+space` and type a word that I would like to look up in the dictionary. If the word is Danish (my native language) it shows me the Danish definitions—that is fine. When I look up a English word, it shows me the translation from English to Dutch, which is really annoying.

Does anybody have a solution to that?

The dictionary works fine, if I just right click a word, and look it up.

---

I have the following dictionaries enables under the dictionary preferences:
[image: Dictionary settings]

And the following Language and Region settings under system preferences:
[image: System settings]

And lastly, my keyboard input language is Danish.

---

## Update

I don't know what happen but suddenly the spotlight dictionary works again. After reindexing spotlight several times, disable and enable definitions in spotlight preferences several times I gave up, and disabled it for good. However, yesterday I enabled spotlight definitions again to state my point to a friend and it works. Strange, but nice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in your question!

This is the image you provided:
[image: Dictionary Preferences]

Notice how it says "Drag reference sources into the order you prefer?" If you notice, the first thing on the list is "English-Dansk". Try dragging "Oxford Dictionary of English" into the spot above "English-Dansk" and see if that provides the answer you are looking for.

Comment: It does not change anything in spotlight, when rearranging them. And the weird thing is, that the Dutch dictionary is disabled, but spotlight still use it. It seems like the spotlight definition settings are different from the dictionary settings.

Comment: Maybe try reindexing spotlight after you make the change I suggested?

Comment: I have tried that too, as well as turn the definitions functionality off and on. Still the same.